# Is there an elegant way to track the modification of all columns of one table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, audit

There is a table in my database containing 100 columns. I want to create a trigger to audit the modification for every update operation.

What I can think is to create the update clause for all columns but they are all similar scripts. So is there any elegant way to do that?

Comment: I can only think of obvious "brute force" methods. Looking forward to seeing any "elegant" solutions to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx)

Update
CDC provides tracking of all details of changes. Available since SQL Server 2008.

*(Change data capture is available only on the Enterprise, Developer, and Evaluation editions of SQL Server.
Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx)*

More lightweight solution is  [Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462.aspx) (Sync Framework), the one [code4life mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933881/is-their-an-elegant-way-to-track-the-modification-of-all-columns-of-one-table-in/3933939#3933939), available since SQL Server 2005.

Update2:
Related questions (with a lot of sublinks):

- History tables pros, cons and gotchas - using triggers, sproc or at application level
  [History tables pros, cons and gotchas - using triggers, sproc or at application level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250507/history-tables-pros-cons-and-gotchas-using-triggers-sproc-or-at-application-l/1250541#1250541)
- Suggestions for implementing audit tables in SQL Server?
  [Suggestions for implementing audit tables in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823/suggestions-for-implementing-audit-tables-in-sql-server)
- Are soft deletes a good idea?
  [Are soft deletes a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549839/are-soft-deletes-a-good-idea)
- How do I version my MS SQL database in SVN?
  [Versioning SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173/how-do-i-version-my-ms-sql-database-in-svn)
- Thomas LaRock. SQL Server Audit: Magic without a Wizard
  http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-audit-magic-without-a-wizard/

Comment: Funny, I recall I've read that CDC requires EE but cannot find any reference. ChangeTracking is edition independent, correct?

Answer (score 1):

There's this resource on MSDN which you might find helpful:

[Tracking Changes in the Server Database (including SQL Server 2008)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726006.aspx)

I'm not sure if you're using SQL Server 2008 though.

Comment: To be fair, the title didn't say that when code4life answered

Comment: @sza could you elaborate? There are other resources that I didn't mention, perhaps these are a better fit...

Answer (score 1):

Code generation?

Have you looked at the techniques which http://autoaudit.codeplex.com/ uses?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you can use 1 trigger and check COLUMNS_UPDATED() to know which columns has changed.
(not be tested)
See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx)