# Entity Framework - Track changes and rollback

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, logging

At the moment I've got a big Entity Data Model (.edmx) with a database underneath it. Now I want to give people who use my site the option to edit those entities but only after I gave approval of the change.

So this would mean that I want to "change" the entity but not really save it yet, after I accepted the change it would override the enity with the changed one. But when I did this I would still like to be able to rollback the change afterwards.

Now I've come up with a few solutions:

> 1) Make a entity with like: [ID], [ChangeApplyDate] [ChangeApproveDate] [Entity before change] [Entity after change] [Accepted (boolean)]
>
> 2) Make an extra entity with the changed values and a link to the "Original" entity and have a boolean in this entity if it is the current approved one or not. (this would not create a new table but expand the table like, "Book", with a few extra properties.

Now I would like to know how you think about those solutions and if you ever made something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things here:

1. Keep a list of all previous versions. Have a look at my answer to this question: [Ideas on database design for capturing audit trails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051449/ideas-on-database-design-for-capturing-audit-trails/1051494#1051494)
2. Controll the acceptance of changes. To do this you could add an approval flag to each table, which only you have access to.

Comment: I'll read your link in a moment, but with the second choice I would have multiple versions of the entity in the same table (but with a approval flag) wouldnt that be a huge waste of database space?

Comment: I looked at the link and that is a genius solution. Thanks alot, this helped me miles!