# Audit trail design

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, database-design

Currently working on ASP.Net MVC 4 application. I have been asked to log all the changes by the user in the application. Its nothing but `Audit Trail`

Here is my controller code

```
 public ActionResult SaveBasicInfo(PatientBasicInfoViewModel basicInfoViewModel)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var loggedInUserPersonId = ((User)Session["CurrentUser"]).PersonId;
            long tenantId = TenantContext.TenantId;
            var patient = Mapper.Map<PatientBasicInfoViewModel,
                                    Patient>(basicInfoViewModel);
            patient.TenantId = tenantId;

            if (patient.PatientId > 0)
            {
                patient.UpdatedBy = loggedInUserPersonId;
                patient.UpdatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                patientService.UpdatePatientDetails(patient);                  
                //Here need to do Audit Log 
                //Current User modified this fields values from `xx` to `yy` on               
            }
            else
            {
                patient.AddedBy = loggedInUserPersonId;
                patientService.AddPatient(patient);
               // Here need to Log, This user created this patient record on Date
            }


          return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = patient.PatientId });
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Details");
    }
```

Could some one help me to design the table structure for this which is flexible for all the combination.

Also **How do i get both the old and new values to be logged?**

Also referred [Ideas on database design for capturing audit trails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051449/ideas-on-database-design-for-capturing-audit-trails?rq=1), but didn't get :(

**Alternative Solution:** creating a shadow/history table for each table that needs audit and use database Trigger. explained [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/etechmentor/audit-trail-system/).

Problem with this is , how i know this column value was changed from this to that by this user? I need to show all the history by user and also for a record

**Note:** ***We are not using Entity Framework, we use simple stored procedure and ADO.Net and use POCO classes***

Help me to choose the best one from below referred **[here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506085627/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041807-1.shtml)**

1. A Separate "History" Table for Each Table Being Audited
2. A Consolidated "History" Table for All Tables Whose Changes are Being Tracked

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051449/ideas-on-database-design-for-capturing-audit-trails?rq=1 duplicate.

Comment: @NevilleK, I referred already and raised a question

Comment: I suggest you learn some real SQL and create some triggers against the db to automagically fire off the logging on change

Comment: @Jason, writing trigger will impact the performance? I often hear `trigger` is not good

Comment: @Billa use the right tool for the job, it's like saying using a thread synchronization construct, e.g. `lock`, will impact performance, sure it will, but what's your other choice?  Don't do multi-threading  :)

Comment: @billa, logging every database interaction is going to give you much worse performance than a well designed trigger.

Comment: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041807-1.shtml

Answer (score 1):

in Ado.NET

You can Use DataTable to Retrieve your data ,

You can get the complete change set of modified rows on a datatable using the following

```
 DataTable ChangedDataTable= yourdataTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified);
```

then you can use the DataRowVersion to get the Original and Current Versions for each Modified Row

```
DataRowObject[0, DataRowVersion.Original] //by Column index
DataRowObject["ColumnName", DataRowVersion.Original] //by column name
```

Comment: i dont use Data Table. I use SQL Reader, read and prepare objects

Answer (score 0):

1- Override the SaveChanges Method in your Context Class

2-

```
     public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            var autoDetectChanges = Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled;

            try
            {
                Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

                foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified))
                {
                   // Save entry
// here you can get the Original Values or Current Values
entry.CurrentValues 
entry.OriginalValues
                }

                ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

                Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

                return base.SaveChanges();
            }
            finally
            {
                Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = autoDetectChanges;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The second DetectChanges call is pointless, the SaveChanges method by default calls the DetectChanges method on its own.  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456854%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: if you are using POCOs then POCO entity is not tracked by the ObjectContext. The DetectChanges method is called to synchronize the ObjectStateManager with the current state of the objects. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456854(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: i posted another answer using ADO.NET hope that helps