# Is there a good framework or library for auditing LDAP/Security management behavior in Java?

Tags: java, security, ldap, auditing

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062717/security-monitoring-and-tracking-standards) earlier, and this is an extension to it.  Basically, we need to have auditable logs for legal reasons of permission/user management and authentication attempts.  Our permissions and users are stored in an LDAP service, and I was wondering what auditing libraries were available for usage?  Are there any?  Is it better to use an auditing library that is a little higher level?  Are there any good resources on what auditing should be and how it is traditionally done?

Comment: What kind of ldap server are you using? AD, e-D, OpenLdap ?

Comment: I believe it is OpenLdap, although I would prefer an answer that was independent of the particular server implementation, if that was at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, what you are looking for, is particular for each Directory server. Because 'Authentication' is more defined as an interface than a feature, and 'Permissions' are just non standard.

**Authentication** is normalized via "`simple bind`" or "`SASL`", but the behaviour of the server (log) are not a standard as far as I know.

**Permissions**, I mean Access Control List (ACLs) are a non standard feature. The way permissions are implemented in Active directory, is different from the way they are implemented in Sun e-Directory (special attributes). For example in OpenLDAP permissions are implented in a kind of access filter.

So my advice is to start from you Directory Server and have a look on what exists.

Answer (score 1):

LDAP keeps its own audit logs, at least OpenLDAP does, or can be made to.